# Are “tremors” and “ tetanic contractions” the same thing?

Tags: terminology, pathology, muscles, neurology

Do these two expressions have the same meaning?

1- Tetanic contractions in the skeletal muscles
2- Rythmic shaking of the hands

(These two expressions are supposed to be two symptoms of Parkinson’s disease ,however I am told that this is repetition)

Comment: I think both for the purpose of convincing your instructors, and for the purpose of asking a well-researched SE question, it would be better if you started with *trying to make your case*. Why do you think they should be considered distinct? What have you learned about these symptoms yourself? Telling a test grader "these should be considered distinct!" is less convincing than "these should be considered distinct because A, B, C, D". I worry that giving you an answer here that you use to debate a test grade is similar to doing homework for you.

Comment: I really appreciate your point of view and admit I have to do better research . But I wish you would at least answer this question :  do you consider them distinct?

Comment: No, I won't, for the reasons I've stated.

Answer (score 1):

**Tetanic contractions and tremor are different phenomena.**

[Tetanic contraction](https://openstax.org/books/anatomy-and-physiology/pages/10-4-nervous-system-control-of-muscle-tension) (or tetanus) refers to sustained contraction of a muscle subjected to high-frequency stimulation. With this high frequency, a new contraction begins before the previous one has ended. Thus the contractions get 'summed up'. You could see [this interesting video](https://youtu.be/hdFZLUx36rY) for a demonstration.

[Tremor](https://www.msdmanuals.com/professional/neurologic-disorders/movement-and-cerebellar-disorders/tremor) is an involuntary shivering movement which is caused by alternating contractions of opposing muscle groups. The causes are many, ranging from physiologic tremor to degenerative disorders of the nervous system (such as [Parkinson disease](https://www.msdmanuals.com/professional/neurologic-disorders/movement-and-cerebellar-disorders/parkinson-disease)).

Note that tetanic contractions are not a symptom of Parkinson disease. In fact they are not a symptom of anything at all, inasmuch as they are a physiological property of isolated muscle. Tremor, on the other hand, is a phenomenon seen in muscle *groups*, and is one of the core symptoms of Parkinson disease.

Comment: What about “rythmic muscle contractions” ? As it is stated here  (https://g.co/kgs/Pvd27p) as a symptom.

Comment: @user261947 The Google page is probably referring to myoclonus, which is sometimes seen in Parkinson disease.